# Angular - FormControl is not binding to formControlName correctly

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm creating a form model manually using `FormGroup & FormControl`, it's fine, but I get an unexpected result when angular binds my `FormControl` to the input it corresponds.

I create the model, and bind to the html this way.

```js
private initFormModel(user: User): FormGroup {
  const _formGroup = new FormGroup({
    fullname: new FormControl({ value: user.name })
  });
  return _formGroup;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is part of the html code / I set on my component class this.form = this.initFormModel(... -->

<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form" novalidate>

<!-- .... --->

<input type="text" formControlName="fullname" name="fullname">
```

**Result**

[image]

There's nothing wrong, if you expect me to use `FormBuilder` it does not change anything. I got `[Object object]` binded to my input, the funny thing is that If I add disabled attribute to my form control definition, it will work well. Like: `fullname: new FormControl({ value: user.name, disabled: false })` I got the text binded, also If I use the Array notation to create the FormControl (`fullname: [user.name, ...]`).

**Just in case I'm currently using Angular v2.4.10**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl):

> When instantiating a FormControl, you can pass in an initial value as the first argument. Example:

```
  const ctrl = new FormControl('some value');
```

> You can also initialize the control with a form state object on instantiation, which includes both the value and whether or not the control is disabled. **You can't use the value key without the disabled key; both are required to use this way of initialization.**

```
  const ctrl = new FormControl({value: 'n/a', disabled: true});
```

(emphasis mine)

Comment: This is great I also took I look at angular source code for `FormControl`. Can you add this to your answer? https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.0-RC.0/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L579 If the type of formState is equals to object, it will check for value, and disabled properties to be present. Otherwise will return false, and `this._value` will never be set. This is the line of usage https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.0-RC.0/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L767